# How much value does Human factor's CUA certification hold for a Senior web developer?

Tags: usability, ux-field, training, usability-engineering

I am working as Senior web developer with 5 years of experience. I also create wireframe mockups and have good experience in photoshop.

I am looking to pursue HFI's CUA certification.

Is this certification of any value from a front-end developer's perspective?

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! Check out the [help] and [about] page to learn more about getting the most out of this community. This question doesn't fit in the scope of this site as it's about the UX profession instead of being a question about UX.

Comment: This question has been asked in different forms previously. [Search for CUA and take a look at the top questions.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=cua)

Answer (score 1):

I got the CUA certification about 10 years back, hasn't helped yet.

Comment: This is really not an answer as it just states your opinion.You need to mention why it has not helped.